# VBA\Excel countdown timer showing incorrect number of hours

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying different code for a countdown timer.  This one does countdown, but I'm unable to get it to countdown from the correct number of hours:minutes:seconds.

when I click on the target cell, it shows in correct hhhhhhh:mm:ss format, and when I click in the editing bar, it shows the correct date\time, but the number of hours is way off in the actual counter text box.

Target date is 12:01:2021 (22,824 hours) but the countdown is displaying 1068743:32:09 hours:minutes:seconds.

I tried the Excel serial number (41244) but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas why I'm not getting the correct value?

I'm guessing it's in the "Dim gcount As Date" statement but am not sure.

Thanks!

```
Dim gCount As Date
'Update 20211201' 

Sub Timer()
    gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub

Sub ResetTime()
   Dim xRng As Range
   Set xRng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C1")
   xRng.Value = xRng.Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
   If xRng.Value <= 0 Then
      MsgBox "Countdown complete."
      Exit Sub
   End If
   Call Timer
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, on  a whim I entered the number of days in the target cell and it's now counting down from the correct number of hours:minutes:seconds.